# sendKeys(protractor.Key.Tab) is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, protractor

I'm using protractor with Javascript. `SendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB)` is not tabbing out from the input field.

Below is the html tag input tag:

```
<td>
  <input class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" type="text" placeholder="Add a new member" ng-blur="addMember()" ng-model="newMemberText"/>
</td>
```

Below is the protractor code snippet i wrote:

```
this.When(/^add member to registration$/, function () {
    var abc= element(by.model('newMemberText'));
    abc.sendKeys('print');
    abc.sendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB);
});
```

I have even tried `abc.sendKeys(KeyboardEvent.TAB)`. Both of them are not working.

Comment: What error / Exception it is throwing?

Comment: you have to check if the issue is with the site under test or it is with Protractor.

Comment: @Helping Hands: It is not throwing any exception

Comment: Did you put try catch() ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you must send the desired key to the browser object, like this:

```
browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB).perform();
```

Comment: Which version of protractor are you using? I tried with protractor 2.1.0 with Chrome "44.0.2403.157 m" and it worked fine. For this command to work properly you have to set the cursor on the field which you want to send 'tab' key

Comment: I'm using protractor 1.8.0. If i use any version above 1.8.0 i'm getting compatibility issues with cucumber (Used to write BDD test cases). My test cases stop working if i upgrade protractor.

Comment: i have downloaded protractor 2.2.0 and checked. it is still  not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds related to [Keys.ENTER, Keys.TAB, Keys.SPACE are not working on Chrome 44](https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1159).

What you need to do:

- update Chrome itself to the latest stable version
- update `chromedriver` to the latest version

Or, if that does not solve your issue, you can always switch to Firefox.

Comment: I just verfied the chrome version. It is 44.0.2403.125 m and it says up-to-date. Also verified the chrome and selenium webdriver. both are up-to-date.

Comment: @AbhishekSN could u please also try with chrome 45 from a beta channel? Thanks (I remember that helped me in a similar issue recently)

Comment: How can i download the chrome 45 beta? Is there a way to do it without using beta version? It would not be recommended to use beta version for testing.

Comment: @AbhishekSN just for the sake of testing and debugging, try upgrading to 45 (which is now beta) and check if you still can reproduce the problem. Thanks.